# function open () in C starts and never ends

Tags: c, unix

```
int j = 1;

if((estado = open(SHELL, O_WRONLY))== -1){

        if(errno == ENOENT){
                
            mkfifo(SHELL,0666);
            estado = open(SHELL, O_WRONLY);
        }

        else{ 
            perror("Erro a abrir pipe de estado da shell : "); 
            exit(1); 
        }
    }

    write (estado, &j,1);
    /************************************************/
```

for some reason this program never computes after one of these open() (don't know which one) it just stalls and keeps there doing something forever... Am I missing anything?

EDIT: I want to thank everyone who answered, I was able to understand better how pipes work with your help and solve my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you find out which one?

Comment: Probably yes, you are missing something.  What that is, we cannot say, because you cannot give us the specific code that is failing.  Try running your program in a debugger, or even just inserting print statements, to determine exactly where the code is failing.

Comment: You don't create a reader of the FIFO. When this app blocks on the open, I'd guess you could open another shell and use cat to open SHELL (whatever its name is), and you'll see the open and write succeed.

Comment: a pipe requires both ends to be open  so it is hanging on the write, waiting for some one to open the pipe for reading.  BTW: what is the contents of 'SHELL' (which has to be a char array or pointer to a char array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by sjnarv (I didn't the comment it until I was finished with my answer...), an `open()` call for writing to a FIFO will block until the FIFO is opened for reading by either another thread or another process.